# Laravel sync makes a duplicate date in pivot table if multiple images selected

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-7

Why does sync makes duplicate sync in the pivot table if i selects more than an image ?

In my application when adding a new competition a user can select one or more images/documents and the file path will be saved in the files table and sync the data into the `competition_file` pivot table.

Here's the create UI

[image]

Here's the store function on my controller

```
  public function store($competition, Request $request, Team $team)
    {

        if ($request->has('photos') && is_array($request->photos)) {

            $files = $this->filesRepo->getByUuids($request->photos);

            $fileId = $files->pluck('id')->toArray();

            if ($files->isNotEmpty()) {

                $forSync = array_fill_keys($fileId, ['competition_id' => $competition,'team_id' => $request->team,'type' => $request->type,'share_type' => $request->share_type]);

                $team->documents()->sync($forSync);

            }
        }

        return redirect(route('documents.index',$competition))->with('success', 'Document updated.');

    }
```

Here's the relationship codes in my model

```
  public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(File::class,'competition_file','team_id','file_id')->wherePivot('type', 'document');
}
```

When i selectes more than one image as below it makes a duplicate in the `competition_file` table

[image]

This is how it saves in the `competition_file` pivot table with a duplicate data

[image]

But if Dump the data before `sync` while I have selected two images it shows only two array see below codes

```
 public function store($competition, Request $request, Team $team)
    {

        if ($request->has('photos') && is_array($request->photos)) {

            $files = $this->filesRepo->getByUuids($request->photos);

            $fileId = $files->pluck('id')->toArray();

            if ($files->isNotEmpty()) {

                $forSync = array_fill_keys($fileId, ['competition_id' => $competition,'team_id' => $request->team,'type' => $request->type,'share_type' => $request->share_type]);

                dd($forSync);

                $team->documents()->sync($forSync);

            }
        }

        return redirect(route('documents.index',$competition))->with('success', 'Document updated.');

    }
```

Result

[image]

And if I remove the `Dump` and reloads the same page it syncs correctly

[image]

And if I retry without `Dump` and if I selects two image and save it creates a duplicate ?

I need to know what might be creating the duplicate sync.

I hope my question is clear, can someone please help me out.

Comment: Set unique constraint on DB level (i.e. `['competition_id', 'team_id', 'file_id'] as unique_competition_team_file`) then continue your work. You'll need to change request validation by checking if same file already exists (probably with custom rule class) but you'll protect your DB against junk data which is (should be) ultimate goal.

Comment: You don't need `'team_id' => $request->team` in the array_fill_keys, since the sync is happening via `documents` relation on team object - team_id should get filled automatically

Comment: @Donkarnash how come the team id gets filled automatically ?
while the user needs to select a team when adding files

Comment: @Donkarnash a user can select team 1 or team 2 when adding a file that's the reason why I have used `'team_id' => $request->team`

Comment: @Donkarnash but if I remove the `$forSync = array_fill_keys($fileId, ['competition_id' => $competition,'type' => $request->type,'share_type' => $request->share_type]);`  and submits the `team_id` will be synced null, what might be the issue ?

Comment: But then what is the $team parameter in the method injection? When you are syncing a related record the id of the model instance which is calling the relation is filled automatically - which is the benefit apart from that it removes the records for ids which are not present in the sync

Comment: `team_id will be synced null ?` No it will automatically fill the team_id with the $team->id. If you need the team_id correspond to the one in $request, then you can do Team::findOrFail($request->team)->documents()->sync([...])

Comment: @Donkarnash when I `dd($team->id);` it shows null ?

Comment: Then you should try `$forSync = array_fill_keys($fileId, ['competition_id' => $competition,'type' => $request->type,'share_type' => $request->share_type]);` and `Team::findOrFail($request->team)->documents()->sync($forSync);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the benefit of subsequent visitors.

```php
public function store($competition, Request $request, Team $team)
{

    if ($request->has('photos') && is_array($request->photos)) {

        $files = $this->filesRepo->getByUuids($request->photos);

        $fileId = $files->pluck('id')->toArray();

        if ($files->isNotEmpty()) {

            $forSync = array_fill_keys($fileId, [
                'competition_id' => $competition,
                'type' => $request->type,
                'share_type' => $request->share_type
            ]);

                
            //If the implicit route model binding is not working
            //if $team is null or you need to explicitly set the team
            //selected by user and which is not passed as route param
            Team::findOrFail($request->team)->documents()->sync($forSync);

        }
    }

    return redirect(route('documents.index',$competition))
        ->with('success', 'Document updated.');

}
```